Le terme « surpressurisation » existe-t-il etc. ?
Concernant un appareil servant à mesurer la concentration de certains constituants d'un gaz, je dois dire qu'il faut moduler la pression en entrée pour éviter la « surpression | surpressurisation », essentiellement l'idée du « over pressurization ». Mais on dirait que le deuxième terme n'existe pas en français, je ne le trouve pas dans des dictionnaires, on dirait une forme de calque généré par des robots qui semble y voir une nuance, même si je trouve « surpressuriser ».
Le terme « surpressurisation » existe-t-il, la possibilité du verbe impliquerait-t-elle automatiquement que le substantif existe, quelle serait la différence entre les deux termes et lequel conviendrait ici ?

Bienvenue, le terme qui convient dépend du message à communiquer - est-ce qu'on veut éviter l'acte de surpressurisation ou la conséquence qui serait la surpression ? J'ai tendance à être d'accord avec la réponse de Frank qui disait que ça revient au même et qu'il vaut mieux un terme plus simple - dommage qu'elle ait disparu.

@guillaume31 La réponse est de retour, dans un univers où tous les termes sont applicables à tous les domaines on peut penser ainsi, mais il est assez probable que le terme surpressurisation ne soit pas directement applicable à l'extérieur du champ de l'aéronautique.

gaz naturel Dans ce document on voit: surpressurisation du reservoir, deux fois https://infoterre.brgm.fr/rapports/RP-55158-FR.pdf. Cela parmi d'autres. Il y a aussi: surpressurisation à l'azote.

Dans le document on trouve surtout 36 fois surpression. @Lambie. Une réponse qui compare tous les contextes d'emploi dans le document par rapport au mien serait utile.

Je vous donne les occurrences, rien de plus. En tout cas, surpression et le processus surpressurisation ne sont pas les même mots.

@Lambie Je comprends, merci, mais moi aussi je peux trouver des occurrences aléatoirement dans des sites et des documents. C'est leur interprétation qui fait la différence.

Lá tu te trompes. Je ne pense pas que le BRGM soit une référence "aléatoire". Et des articles/sites français d'organismes comme celui-là constituent des sources fiables - à part les glossaires spécialisés - pour le vocabulaire technique. Je vois qu'aucune réponse donne une référence. Et ici, cela est souvent le cas. Ce qui compte c'est l'utilisation des termes par des experts "sur le terrain" dans leur langue maternelle.

Et ces experts utilisent 36 fois surpression et 2 fois surpressurisation dans leur document @Lambie. Tu pourrais au moins faire le lien entre ces 2 emplois et la question.

Le nombre de fois un mot est utilisé ne nous dit pas grande chose.

@Lambie [pas grand chose].

Le nombre de fois un mot est utilisé ne nous dit pas grand-chose.

@Lambie [Le nombre de fois qu'un mot...]

Le mot pressurisation signifie l'action d'augmenter la pression de l'air présent dans une enceinte close, typiquement un avion, par rapport à la pression extérieure afin de maintenir les passagers en vie et en évitant plus généralement les effets secondaires d'une pression trop basse.
Dans ce contexte, surpressurisation signifie l'action d'augmenter cette pression au delà de la pression atmosphérique au sol. Le préfixe sur- est régulier et il est encore productif donc rien n'interdit d'utiliser ce néologisme qui ne choquera pas.
On peut quand même noter qu'il existe déjà un adjectif au sens proche, hyperbare qui peut produire un substantif concurrent : hyperbarisation.
Dans un contexte industriel, on peut trouver  des sources où surpressurisation a été choisi pour traduire l'anglais overpressurization (cf. lien fourni par Lambie).

Overpressurization: Exposure of equipment to pressures in excess of the design pressure.
Source

On trouve cependant surpression avec le même sens dans la totalité des documents officiels français :

A l’occasion du fonctionnement des accessoires de sécurité, un dépassement de courte durée de la pression maximale admissible, lorsque cela est approprié, est admis. La surpression momentanée est limitée à 10% de la pression maximale admissible.
Arrêté du 20 novembre 2017 relatif au suivi en service des équipements sous pression et des récipients à pression simples

Supressurisation sera compris mais semble redondant, voire impropre, dans ce contexte puisqu'il s'agit d'une surpression accidentelle.
La seule utilisation officielle de supressurisation concerne les équipements de protections NRBC (Nucléaire, Radioactivité, Biologique, Chimique) où la pression à l'intérieur de combinaisons ou au moins d'un masque est volontairement maintenue au dessus de la pression atmosphérique extérieure pour éviter une contamination des personnes.

Il s'agit là d'une extension naturelle de pressurisation.

Pressuriser et ses dérivés sont des anglicismes qui se sont banalisés au 20ème s, notamment dans l'aviation civile, supplantant "mettre sous pression".  +1 pour le rappel d'hyperbare; ce mot est connoté "maintenu à une pression si élevée que l'azote respiré reste dissous dans le sang".

On pourrait peut-être voir une nuance, si surpressurisation existait. Par exemple surpression signifierait que la pression d'un gaz est excessive, alors que surpressurisation voudrait dire que le processus qui met le gaz sous pression est excessif, puisque pressurisation signifierait: "mettre sous pression".
Mais pourquoi ne pas opter pour la simplicité, et simplement utiliser surpression, puisque le résultat est le même: la pression du gaz est excessive.

Il y a une faible nuance entre les deux mots, le premier indique l'action de rendre la pression trop élevée, le second le fait d'avoir une pression trop élevée.

Dans le cas présent, j'opterai plutôt pour excès de pression.

Le terme « surpressurisation » existe-t-il ?
Oui, comme en fait foi une réponse, le terme existe, et semble particulièrement s'appliquer à une « enceinte close, typiquement un avion » (jlliagre).
La possibilité du verbe impliquerait-t-elle automatiquement que le substantif existe ?
L'existence est une chose, l'usage en est une autre.
Quelle serait la différence entre les deux termes et lequel conviendrait ici ?
Comme l'indique une autre réponse, on veut y voir une nuance entre l'état (sous pression), l'action qui mène à un état (pressurisation), voire une action légèrement différente qui mène à un état excessif (surpressurisation). (Frank)
Le terme surpression convient le mieux à mon avis, car il n'est pas connoté/relié à l'aéronautique et relève plus de la physique générale. De plus, l'élément de l'analyseur dans lequel le gaz circule n'a pas exactement les propriétés d'une enceinte close et la référence n'est pas une pression normale et une pression d'une cabine etc. mais bien une tolérance arbitraire d'un appareil basée sur les instructions du fabricant. L'action principale est l'introduction du gaz par l'analyste et non l'augmentation de pression.
